# What are some rules to follow when using alias names along with subqueries?

Tags: sql, subquery, alias

I'm confused after seeing these two snippets, one works, the other not. So there's one table `MyTable` with two columns: `ID` and `Value`

Snippet 1 (Failed)

```
/*Find the ID that is related to the maximum value*/
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable AS t /*Here MyTable can be a complex subquery. MyTable is just a placeholder here to show you can't use alias t in the subquery after WHERE*/
WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM t) /*Get error here: 'Invalid object name t"*/
```

Snippet 2 (Worked)

```
/*Rank Value column*/
SELECT ID, Value,
(SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM MyTable WHERE Value >= t.Value) AS Rank /*No error raised here for t.Value*/
FROM MyTable AS t
```

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163941/invalid-object-name-after-aliasing-a-table) post explains that

> One cannot reference an alias from a subquery at the same scope

But what is `the same scope`? Does it explain why snippet 2 works? I assume there are other possible ways of using aliases and subqueries in different positions (like in different clauses or nest in different ways). So are there any general error-proof rules to follow when using aliases with subqueries?

(Please don't use view-like tricks such as CTE or workarounds such as TOP and LIMIT)

Comment: A "table alias" aka correlation name denotes a row, not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the first query.

```
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM t)
```

This would try to select from the table alias `t`.
Which isn't allowed.  It should select from a table or view.

For example:

```
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable)
```

Note that this doesn't have to do with scope. 
It's also not allowed without using any sub-queries.

For example, this would fail for the same reason

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM MyTable AS t1
JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Then we have the second query.

```
SELECT ID, Value,
( 
    SELECT COUNT(Value) 
    FROM MyTable t1sub
    WHERE t1sub.Value >= t1out.Value
) AS Rank
FROM MyTable AS t1out
```

This is called a correlated subquery.
That sub-query links the current `t1out.Value` of the outer query to the table in the sub-query via t1sub.Value.

It re-executes the sub-query for each row from the outer query.

About the scope.
It's about what a part of the SQL can look at and use.

In the previous SQL, the `t1sub` alias is only known within the scope of the correlated sub-query.
The outer query doesn't even know about the alias `t1sub` that's used in the sub-query.
While inside the correlated subquery, the `t1out.Value` can be seen and used.

Some tests can be found on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1cf22e5a21c2e74687dd80d60d57dd70)*

Comment: I re-edited my post for that `T` and `t` confusion.

Comment: Btw, based on those queries I have a hunch that you're still on a database version that doesn't support the window functions.  These days, in most current versions of the RDBMS, those kind of things could be solved with window functions like ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK, etc...

Comment: Well, maybe I could word even more simple.  Queries can only look at what's above them. And the outer-query is on top.  And aliases are often just used to make the SQL shorter. F.e. compare this: `select t.col1, t.col2 from Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious as t` versus this: `select Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.col1, Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.col2 from Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`

Comment: Is it safe to say If I have an alias `t`, then I can only see this (unqualified) `t` once (when it's defined), although I may see `t.colname` many times?

Comment: And for scope, let's say we have (t1)t2(t3). I understand t2 cannot see t1 or t3, and t1, t3 can both see t2. But can t1 and t3 see each other? Or can t4 see t1 in (t1)t2(t3(t4))? (Ok, I know I'm being pedantic now, I will accept your answer anyway lol)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `(t1)t2(t3(t4))`. It depends on the SQL.

Comment: Each pair of parentheses defines a (sub)query.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query should work:

```
SELECT ID
FROM <tablename> t
WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM <tablename>) ;
```

You cannot use the alias to refer the the whole table again (which is what I think you were doing, but but the table and the alias are `t` in the actual example).

Instead, the alias is used to refer to *columns* in the table.  This allows you to associate columns with the right table -- so the query unambiguously does what you intend.

Comment: I re-edited my post for that `T` and `t` confusion. Maybe snippet 1 is not a good example because you can simply use the original table in FROM. But in many cases that is a derived table

Comment: @Nicholas . . . The alias is to qualify column references.  It is not a reference to the entire table.  If you wanted that, you could use a CTE.